# Converting DAV to MP4 and OGG

Tags: video, browser, ffmpeg, html5-video, ogg

I want to prepare WEB page containing films from security camera recorders. Each recorder transmit video files in DAV format so each film is converted to MP4 format by script, using such syntax:

```
ffmpeg -y -i movie.dav -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 movie.mp4
```

So I included in HTMLv5 code such entry:

```
 <video width="320" height="240">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It works correctly with Chrome but not with Firefox. For proper work in FF it is necessary add link to OGG file. So correct HTMLv5 syntax for both browsers should look like this:

```
 <video width="320" height="240">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Can anybody help me to pass correct ffmpeg syntax to create OGG file?

Output from console after using -movflags +faststart options

```
[maciek@piotr MMM]$ ../ffmpeg-2.4.2-64bit-static/ffmpeg -movflags +faststart -y -i   04.24.23-04.24.38\[M\]\[@0\]\[0\].dav -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 10.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.4.2-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  9 2014 07:24:56 with gcc 4.8 (Debian 4.8.3-11)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable- libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-ffserver --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --cc=gcc-4.8
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Option movflags not found.
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `-movflags +faststart` as an output option to your `ffmpeg` command for the MP4 output. It will relocate the MOOV atom to the beginning of the file; otherwise the complete file must be downloaded by the client before playback can occur.

Comment: Yep! Pretty good idea!

Comment: But ffmpeg rapports an error - Option movflags not found. I use ffmpeg ver 2.4.2 linux 64 bit taken from http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ as a static binary

Comment: Impossible to debug without your ffmpeg command and console output.

Comment: So I added console output to the first post

Comment: As I mentioned before it is an output option. You're attempting to apply it to the input. Place it after your input file.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -i movie.dav -vn -acodec libvorbis audiofile.ogg

I did not test this.

Comment: That will create an audio file only, or if the input is only video ffmpeg will output the `does not contain any stream` error an create an empty file.

Comment: Yep. But the problem is that some security cameras has build in microphone and some not. But for proper playback such converted file in Firefox, OGG file is necessary. But in Chrome - not. So does not matter is the audio content included in input stream or not, OGG file must be present HTMLv5 code.

Comment: So what to do in above case?

Comment: Yes. it creates empty file but it is OK. The problem I have is that browser display only controls for video clip and time of the clip is "zero". I use WEB page http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video for test. The only thing I chage is filename loation to ->  https ://192.168.0.7/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Filmy/Kamery/1.mp4
and https ://192.168.0.7/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Filmy/Kamery/1.ogg. Can anybody halt me whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve the same problem and i actually found a solution even if not by using ffmpeg.

I tried this on Windows but i guess it won't make any difference if it is done on Linux.

To convert .dav files i used VLC like this:

1) Go to Tools --> Preferences in the VLC toolbar.

2) Then select "All" in the Show Setting field in the bottom-left corner.

3) Go in the "Demuxers" section and switch from "Automatic" to "H264 video demuxer" and Save.
4) Then again from the VLC toolbar, go to Media --> Convert/Save...

5) Select Add and chose the file you wish to convert.

6) Press the arrow on the "Convert/Save" button and select Convert

7) Then chose a "Destination File" in the section below clicking on Browse

8) Finally press "Start" and wait for the VLC progress bar to be full.

At this point the file should be successfully converted.

Anyway after step 3 you should already be able to play the .dav file so to check if it is not corrupted try playing it first.

Hope the answer will be useful to somebody and i wish you all a good day :)

EDIT: this answer of course is not fully related to the question because i don't know if the information is usefull in any way for Web Pages :\ so, sorry for not remaining exactly on topic

Answer (score -1):

I have a answer just try it.

Install this Nuget NReco.VideoConverter

Package Manage Console

```
Install-Package NReco.VideoConverter -Version 1.1.2
```

and this method to convert

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(inputfile.dav, "output.mp4", Format.mp4);
```

Comment: This doesnt answer the question at all.